# Is there an event when all observers have unsubscribed from an Observable?

Tags: rx-java

I have an `Observable` that I want to be cold, that is, it should only start emitting items when the first observer subscribes to it.

Then, I want to make sure to release all the resources from the source when all observers unsubscribe from that same observable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the functionality of a ConnectedObservable to handle this for you:

```
//Replace Observable.range(1,1000) with your Observable implementation
Observable.range(1, 1000).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> freeResources()).share();
```

`share` method calls methods `publish` and `refCount` .

`publish` transforms your "normal" Observable into a ConnectedObservable, which will start emitting items the moment you call `connect`. Therefore you could technically subscribe as many observers as you want, and then call `connect` to start emitting items for all of them at the same time.

`refCount` transforms your ConnectedObservable back again into a traditional one, but with new characteristics! The added benefits are: this observable is now cold (only starts emitting when a subscriber subscribes, internally it calls the `connect` method of the original ConnectedObservable created with `publish`), and keeps track of how many subscribers are connected to the original ConnectedObservable. Once all subscribers have unsubscribed, it will unsusbcribe from the source ConnectedObservable, therefore the logic becomes much simpler as you only need to handle one subscription.

There is a good diagram for the share operation here: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#share()

Alternatively, if this is not flexible enough, I think you should be able to achieve this behaviour easily by using `defer` in order to create a cold observable, and the `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnUnsubscribe` methods.

Example:

```
    Observable.defer(() -> {
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        return Observable.range(1, 1000)
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> counter.incrementAndGet())
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
                    if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        freeResources();
                    }
                });
    });
```

This observable will start emitting a sequence of numbers (replace this with your observable implementation) as soon as the first subscriber subscribes, it will increase a counter with each subscription, and free the used resources once all the subscribers have unsubscribed (replace freeResources for whatever you need).